# Using rotation of proxies within a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, web-scraping, proxy

I've written a script in Python using rotation of proxies which is able to fetch different titles from a website traversing different pages. I've tried to write this scraper in such a way so that it will try using proxies randomly until it can get the titles from that webpage, meaning it will use every single proxy cyclically if there is any difficulty getting the valid response.

The proxies and site address I've used within my scraper are just placeholders to let you know how I'm trying to do this.

As I do not have much experience about the usage of rotation of proxies within a scraper, there may be flaws within the design. It is working errorlessly, though.

I will be very glad if I get any suggestions as to how I can improve this existing script to make it more robust.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from random import choice

ua = UserAgent()

search_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page={}&sort=newest'.format(page) for page in range(1,3)]

def get_proxies():
    proxies = ['128.199.254.244:3128', '95.85.79.54:53281', '128.199.125.54:2468', '178.45.8.113:53281', '206.189.225.30:3128']
    return proxies

def check_proxy(session,proxy):
    session.headers = {'User-Agent', ua.random}
    session.proxies = {'https': 'https://{}'.format(proxy)}
    try:
        response = session.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
        item = response.json()
        print(item)
        return 0  ##if the proxy is a working one, break out of the function
    except Exception:
        proxy = random_proxy()
        check_proxy(session,proxy)  ##if the earlier one is not working, try moving on to fetch the working one

def random_proxy():
    return choice(get_proxies())

def scrape_page(url):
    proxy = random_proxy() 
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {'User-Agent', ua.random}
    session.proxies = {'https': 'https://{}'.format(proxy)}
    check_proxy(session,proxy) ##try validating the proxy before further attempt 

    try:
        response = session.get(url)
    except Exception:
        response = None  #preventing "UnboundLocalError:"
        check_proxy(session,proxy) #if try block failed to execute the response, activate it

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    for items in soup.select(".question-hyperlink"):
        print(items.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for link in search_urls:
        scrape_page(link)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `scrape_page()` with some URL, you end up making at least two requests: at least one request to verify that the randomly chosen proxy works, and then to make the main request.  Isn't that overhead a bit excessive?  Why not optimistically assume that a proxy works, and verify the proxy only if the main request fails?

If many requests fail — for example, if your network is down — then your program would get stuck in a tight, infinite retry loop.  Even a 0.1-second delay in the exception handler would be very helpful to prevent the CPU from going haywire.

The code in `check_proxy()` is a bit redundant with the code in `scrape_page()`.  Also, `check_proxy()` is inappropriately recursive.  I would create a `set_proxy()` function that has a more comprehensive mission.

Instead of assuming that each proxy is HTTPS, I would write the URL of each proxy with the explicit protocol, then infer the protocol by parsing the URL.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from random import choice
import requests
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import urlparse

PROXIES = [
    'https://128.199.254.244:3128',
    'https://95.85.79.54:53281',
    'https://128.199.125.54:2468',
    'https://178.45.8.113:53281',
    'https://206.189.225.30:3128',
]

def set_proxy(session, proxy_candidates=PROXIES, verify=False):
    """
    Configure the session to use one of the proxy_candidates.  If verify is
    True, then the proxy will have been verified to work.
    """
    while True:
        proxy = choice(proxy_candidates)
        session.proxies = {urlparse(proxy).scheme: proxy}
        if not verify:
            return
        try:
            print(session.get('https://httpbin.org/ip').json())
            return
        except Exception:
            pass

def scrape_page(url):
    ua = UserAgent()
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
    set_proxy(session)

    while True:
        try:
            response = session.get(url)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            session.headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
            set_proxy(session, verify=True)
            sleep(0.1)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    for items in soup.select(".question-hyperlink"):
        print(items.text)
```

Comment: It's a very nice review @200_success. Thanks  a lot. I just wish to know which I should comply `session.headers = {'User-Agent', ua.random}`  or `session.headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}`? Notice the `,` and `:`. Gonna accept it in a while.

Comment: @MITHU The comma would make it a set rather than a dictionary. Bug fixed in Rev 2.